Can't switch to a space with no open windows
When Mission Control preferences When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for that application is enabled, it is not possible to switch to an empty space if a Finder window is open.
I have three spaces that I use for different tasks.
If I open a Finder window in one space, I can no longer switch to the other spaces to launch other programs, because there are not yet any open windows.
If I try from any app besides the Finder, it just dumps me in the Space with the Finder window.
Note: in the Dock options for the Finder, I have "Assign to: None" because I want my Finder windows associated with Spaces.

How are you trying to switch Spaces?

Yes, I am trying to switch Spaces. When I try, it works for 1/2 second, then I get switched back to the space with the open Finder window.

How, precisely, are you switching Spaces?

Three-finger swipe on trackpad. I will try control-arrows.

Cannot replicate the issue despite having that setting enabled. Have you tried dragging app windows from the space where the Finder is to another space? Does it allow you to switch to the other space then?
